VideoView Flickering for a bit before video plays JAVA/XML
I have a video in a class that opens when the user first lands on the app, and is kind of like a nice design added to the instructions on how to actually use the app. However, right before the video starts playing, there is a moment where the screen flickers to black and then the video starts playing.
I have looked at this: Android VideoView black screen, but none of the answers have worked. I also looked a few other ones as well and those haven't worked either.
This is the code I have:
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_layout, container, false);

    ImageView slideImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    VideoView slideVideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    TextView slideHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    TextView slideDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);

    MediaItem item = mediaItems[position];

    if (item.getType() == MediaItem.MediaType.IMAGE) {
        slideImageView.setImageResource(item.getResourceId());
        slideImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        slideVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (item.getType() == MediaItem.MediaType.VIDEO) {
        slideImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        slideVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        // Set the video URI using the resource ID
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + item.getResourceId());
        slideVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        // Start video playback when it's ready
        slideVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                slideVideoView.start();
            }
        });
    }

    slideHeading.setText(headings[position]);
    slideDescription.setText(descriptions[position]);

    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

And here is my XML:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:padding="16dp">

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</FrameLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_image_24" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/heading_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDescription"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/description_1" />

I have an array of images and videos which is where mediaItems is called from. If anything else is needed please comment and I will add it.

I have found an answer a few minutes after posting the question. I took my video view, and set the ZOrderOnTop to true, and then the flicker went away.
The edited lines of code would be
// Set the video URI using the resource ID
   Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + item.getResourceId());
   slideVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

// ADDED LINE 
   slideVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

If there is another way to fix this weird bug, please feel free to reply to this with that answer
